# No es posible cambiar el valor de la propiedad: "checked", usando Jquery (Asp.Net 2.0)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
Estimados un cordial saludo,
```

Estoy intentando seleccionar, "una fila a la vez", utilizando una etiqueta, checkbox, dentro de un GridView; para lo cual, estoy utilizando jquery versión: jquery-3.3.1.js. Sin embargo, siempre hace selección múltiple y no me permite seleccionar **sólo una fila a la vez**. Le agregué una clase en el checkbox para cambiar el valor de su atributo "checked", pero no funciona:
De antemano, muchas gracias por sus comentarios.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grwLista" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        ShowHeader="true" DataKeyNames="codigo" GridLines="None">
          <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Selec.">
                <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelecion" CssClass ="claseChk" runat ="server" 
                             AutoPostBack="false" />                                  
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>   
                       <asp:BoundField DataField="desc_af" HeaderText="NOMBRE" />
                       <asp:BoundField DataField="resp_bien" HeaderText="FECH. NAC." />
                       <asp:BoundField DataField="ubicacion" HeaderText="CIUDAD" />
                                            
 
           </Columns>
                                      
</asp:GridView>
              
               
           

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
           
          
            $("#<%=grwLista.ClientID%> [id*='chkSelecion']").change(function() {

                var chk = $(this).prop('checked');
                
                if (chk == true) {

                     $('.claseChk').prop("checked",false);                  
                     $(this).prop("checked",true);           
                }
                

            });

</script>
```

Comment: Te puede ayudar este enlace [ASP.NET+jQuery: Gridview con checkbox limitando a un solo valor de selección](https://geeks.ms/fernandezja/2012/01/10/asp-netjquery-gridview-con-checkbox-limitando-a-un-solo-valor-de-seleccin/)

Comment: Listo, Muchas Gracias Jose.

Answer (score 1):

encontré una solución para la pregunta mencionada. En mi caso, no se podía llamar al evento "Change", asignado al CheckBox, porque el gridView estaba dentro de un UpdatePanel; el cual, yo actualizaba con el método Update(), propio de asp.net; y según he podido notar; este método Update(), estaba eliminando el evento "Change" (en cada refresh).

**Solución:** Lo que hice es que después de llamar al método, Update(), propio de asp.net, para actualizar el UpdatePanel, utilicé el método: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript y desde ahí llamé a una función javascript para volver a asignar el evento "change" al control checbox; y a partir de ahí, pude evitar la selección múltiple en un checkbox, dentro un GridView y un UpdatePanel, y Listo¡¡¡.

Presento líneas abajo el código necesario, para la solución encontrada:

```
#VISUAL BASIC
                  Me.udpDetalle.Update()
                  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.Page.GetType, "agregarEvento", "agregarEvento();", True)

#ASPX (Segmento de código -> Javascript)

            function agregarEvento()
            {     
              
                       $("#<%=grwDetalle.ClientID%> [id*='chkselecpedido']").change(function() {
                         
                       var chk = $(this).prop('checked');
                    
                       if (chk == true) {
                          $('tbody tr td span.chkFila input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);
                          $(this).prop("checked", true);
                            
                       }               

                     });
            }
```